# How generate scriptfu scheme code in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, automated-refactoring, script-fu

Gimp has script-fu for scripting code in Scheme. But i don't know does ít has the reverse function? It mean, when i draw or do something, can it generate scheme code or any language parallel with that action? I think that will be the best way to learn coding in GIMP. Thanks

i have search at lease 10 google pages and download 1 pdf, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for doesn't exist.

- Scripts are in general not able to change things in the UI (like the zoom factor) nor to interact directly with the UI (like obtain where the user clicked).
- Many single UI actions correspond to a sequence of API calls
- Many API calls do the same as a sequence of mouse clicks
- Sometimes the most efficient way to do something in a script is very different from the "manual" way.

Over the years I have seen several attempts at a "Gimp recorder" but they all fell short.

The best way to learn to code in Gimp is to see examples. All Gimp scripts are open-source by design, and there are thousands of scripts around, either in Scheme or Python.

Comment: So detail and reasonable explain. But forgive me if i wrong. Does it mean a poor design at beginning? Freecad is open source CAD with python scripting, and it have 2 separate objects - one in GUI - one in actions. The problem is, what behind that 2 objects, make a bridge - a link - or what ever to smooth all records. Now, even zoom factor or where the user clicked are counted for. May be with the record generated, it's not most efficient, but it so fast and base on that, we can learn a lot, much more easily modify the process to make thing better.

Comment: It not "poor design". It's "other design choices". Scripting is eventually quite simple in Gimp because you don't need to handle the UI...